# Getting error for post data using windows azure mobile service in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, azure, azure-mobile-services

For send data from POST method using `windows azure mobile service` .
Getting response error response

> message = "An error has occurred."

My post method is and 
 data dictionary is

```
NSDictionary *data = @{@"emailID": @"abc@gmail.comt",
                       @"userPhone": @"",
                       @"password": @"12345678",
                       @"id":@"",
                       @"signUpBy": [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]};
```

And API call function is is

```
 -(void)signUpCallAPI:(NSDictionary *)parameter{

// URL that calls into the Azure Service
NSString *serviceUri = @"https://demo.azure-mobile.net/tables/SignUp";

// Convert to NSURL type
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:serviceUri];

// Create a request object
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                 timeoutInterval:60];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = nil;
if (parameter)
    jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameter
                                               options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                 error:&error];
   // Modify http headers for POST request
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

//Content type what we are sending
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)jsonData.length ] forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-length"];

// Indicate JSON Data Format
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

// Indicate JSON Data Format
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];


// Indicate host property
[request setValue:@"demo.azure-mobile.net" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];

// Indicate application key (you get this from the portal)
[request setValue:@"demoappkey" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-ZUMO-APPLICATION"];

//add data to body
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

// Execute request
conn= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[conn start];}
```

For Post data from signup api not working .
Anything need to do my side?
Any sample available for for post data using API.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to use Mobile Services without using the iOS SDK.  Microsoft has created an SDK for various mobile platform that simplify sending and retrieving data from Mobile Services: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services

I'd suggest you first look at the ToDo sample iOS app: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-get-started/

Next, this article in the Microsoft documentation explains how to add Mobile Services to an existing app: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-get-started-data/

Comment: Geting   Errordomain=com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorDomain Code=-1302 "{"message":"An error has occurred."}" UserInfo=0x7f92a2ee8f60 {NSLocalizedDescription={"message":"An error has occurred."}, com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorRequestKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0>...com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorResponseKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f92a5022110> { URL: https://demo.azure-mobile.net/tables/SignUp } { status code: 500, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 36;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
   ..
} }}

Comment: Using Chrome to navigate to demo.azure-mobile.net/tables/SignUp  returns: {
"code": 404,
"error": "Error: Table 'SignUp' does not exist."
}

Comment: demo word added by me instead of real.  Hard to find where is issue on error code -1302 because its gives only response  **message":"An error has occurred **. Any other way to find an issue on which end( client or server)?

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like Postman or Fiddler to POST directly and see if you get the same error?

Comment: solved my issue .Its working fine now.I missed some fields  to send in request.